# Mongodb distinct on a array field with regex query?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Basically i'm trying to implement tags functionality on a model.

```
> db.event.distinct("tags")
[ "bar", "foo", "foobar" ]
```

Doing a simple distinct query retrieves me all distinct tags. However how would i go about getting all distinct tags that match a certain query? Say for example i wanted to get all tags matching `foo` and then expecting to get `["foo","foobar"]` as a result?

The following queries is my failed attempts of achieving this:

```
> db.event.distinct("tags",/foo/)
[ "bar", "foo", "foobar" ]

> db.event.distinct("tags",{tags: {$regex: 'foo'}})
[ "bar", "foo", "foobar" ]
```

Comment: Just as a "pre-note" here on the answer. It would probably be "nice" if  `.distinct()` respected the "filtering" of arrays just as it naturally handles them. ie. `db.event.distinct("tags",{ "tags": /^foo/ }))` should probably work to "filter" the array content. But on the other hand, there are probably those who **don't** want that to work that way. Hence `.aggregate()` is the "swiss army knife" to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and not the `.distinct()` command:

```js
db.event.aggregate([
    // De-normalize the array content to separate documents
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },

    // Filter the de-normalized content to remove non-matches
    { "$match": { "tags": /foo/ } },

    // Group the "like" terms as the "key"
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$tags"
    }}
])
```

You are probably better of using an "anchor" to the beginning of the regex is you mean from the "start" of the string. And also doing this [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) before you process [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) as well:

```js
db.event.aggregate([
    // Match the possible documents. Always the best approach
    { "$match": { "tags": /^foo/ } },

    // De-normalize the array content to separate documents
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },

    // Now "filter" the content to actual matches
    { "$match": { "tags": /^foo/ } },

    // Group the "like" terms as the "key"
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$tags"
    }}
])
```

That makes sure you are not processing [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on every document in the collection and only those that possibly contain your "matched tags" value before you "filter" to make sure.

The really "complex" way to somewhat mitigate large arrays with possible matches takes a bit more work, and MongoDB 2.6 or greater:

```js
db.event.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "tags": /^foo/ } },
    { "$project": {
        "tags": { "$setDifference": [
            { "$map": {
                "input": "$tags",
                "as": "el",
                "in": { "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ 
                        { "$substr": [ "$$el", 0, 3 ] },
                        "foo"
                    ]},
                    "$$el",
                    false
                ]}
            }},
            [false]
        ]}
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$tags" }}
])
```

So [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) is a nice "in-line" processor of arrays but it can only go so far. The [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator negates the `false` matches, but ultimately you still need to process `$unwind` to do the remaining `$group` stage for distinct values overall.

The advantage here is that arrays are now "reduced" to only the "tags" element that matches. Just don't use this when you want a "count" of the occurrences when there are "multiple distinct" values in the same document. But again, there are other ways to handle that.

Comment: Is the latter query supposed to return : `{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }`?

Comment: @netbrain typo. the "%" was meant to be "^" just like before. You didn't say but I suspect that "tags" is an array. Hence `$unwind`.

Comment: It seems good, need to read up a bit on aggregate's and $unwind.

Comment: @netbrain Well following on from your earlier comment, I usually "comment" in-line to make the intent clear. I've done that now and added the explanation.

Comment: Yes thanks, I understand it better now. however is there anything you would like to say on performance on such a solution? for example the unwind operation seems like it might be a performance hog if the documents are large (seeing as it duplicates the documents in order to normalize the array)?

Comment: @netbrain Yep. So you have spotted the obvious "cost" problem for unwinding an array. The first `$match` is there to "mitigate" this somewhat by removing candidates that cannot possibly match after an `$unwind`. If you do actually mean from the "start" of the string then there is a way to "reduce" that load by eliminating array elements beforehand. It still comes at a cost ( possibly a bit less ), but you ultimately need `$unwind` to process array elements here.

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but.. Would it be better to use `db.event.distinct('tags')` and then postprocess the result from the distinct query and filter it by a query?

Comment: @netbrain It depends on your acutal data. If it's a pretty small distinct result then it is better. If not then at least in modern MongoDB versions you return a "cursor" object ( or can in API ) to then iterate with your "distinct" and "filtered" results. I only answer questions on the obvious calls as I see them. If you're only excluding one result out of four possibles then you would be mad not to process this in client code. Still useful to know how to make the server do this isn't it. Geez you're a hard sell.

Comment: Hehe, sorry about that, i'll accept your answer shortly, I just wanted to get all the facts straight before i did :) Anyways thanks for your help, ill guess Ill have to see how it performs over time. And if needed optimize it on a later date.

Comment: @netbrain Fair enough. And I'm only joking. Good on you for doing your "due dillegance". Glad to inform.

Comment: Glad to be informed :)